# Conditional Date Difference (in months) Lambda Function

Tags: python, date

I am wanting to derive a new column in the data frame I have called `"duration"`.

Not all observations in the data frame have an `end_date` so I created the `end_date` column with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({"column":["other", "value", "value", "other", "value"],
"created":[2022-04-19 7:09, 2022-03-16 0:58, 2021-12-10 0:36, 2022-01-29 18:47, 2022-01-21 10:14])

df["start_date"] = df["created"].dt.date.astype("datetime64[ns]")

for column in df:
    if df[column].name == "column":
        df["end_date"] = df[column].apply(
          lambda x: date.today() if x == "value" else None
    ).astype("datetime64[ns]")
```

What I am wanting to do is get the difference in months between the observation's start and end date **if end_date is NOT null**, otherwise the difference will be between today's date and the observation's start date.

**I know that this difference in calculation doesn't matter** because I have set the `end_date` column to be today's date - **I just want to execute the code with the logic I have**.

Both of these single lines of code get the `duration` (in months) that I want:

```
#difference between end_date and start_date
((df["end_date"] - df["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
```

```
#difference between today's date and end_date
((np.datetime64("today") - df["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
```

I would like to combine both of these lines of code into a lambda function but unfortunately it is not working:

```
df["duration"] = df["end_date"].apply(
    lambda x: ((x - df["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
    if x is not None
    else
    ((np.datetime64("today") - df["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
)
```

With the above block of code, the error I get is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [31], line 1
----> 1 df["duration"] = df["end_date"].apply(
      2     lambda x: ((x - df["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
      3     if x is not None
      4     else
      5     ((np.datetime64("today") - df["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
      6 )

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3602, in DataFrame.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   3600     self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3601 elif isinstance(value, DataFrame):
-> 3602     self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
   3603 elif (
   3604     is_list_like(value)
   3605     and not self.columns.is_unique
   3606     and 1 < len(self.columns.get_indexer_for([key])) == len(value)
   3607 ):
   3608     # Column to set is duplicated
   3609     self._setitem_array([key], value)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3729, in DataFrame._set_item_frame_value(self, key, value)
   3727 len_cols = 1 if is_scalar(cols) else len(cols)
   3728 if len_cols != len(value.columns):
...
   3733 if isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex) and isinstance(
   3734     loc, (slice, Series, np.ndarray, Index)
   3735 ):

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Alternatively, I've tried:

```
df["duration"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ((x["end_date"] - x["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
    if x["end_date"] is not None
    else
    ((np.datetime64("today") - x["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
)
```

But with this block of code I get:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [32], line 1
----> 1 df["duration"] = df.apply(
      2     lambda x: ((x["end_date"] - x["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
      3     if x["end_date"] is not None
      4     else
      5     ((np.datetime64("today") - x["start_date"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "M")).round(1)
      6 )

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:8740, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8729 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
   8731 op = frame_apply(
   8732     self,
   8733     func=func,
   (...)
   8738     kwargs=kwargs,
   8739 )
-> 8740 return op.apply()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:688, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    685 elif self.raw:
    686     return self.apply_raw()
--> 688 return self.apply_standard()
...
    387             raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 388     raise KeyError(key)
    389 return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

KeyError: 'end_date'
```

Comment: "but unfortunately it is not working" *what does that mean exactly*? "it is not working" is not a sufficient description of the problem

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, I will include some more information

Comment: Please post the _full_ traceback, and show an example of your dataframe. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thank you for providing that informative link, it was helpful - as you can probably tell I'm a newbie and have still got a lot to learn

Comment: @PranavHosangadi are still able to help me?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga are you able to help me?